# Not all values storing in a loop

Tags: r, store

I want to store values in "yy" but my code below stores only one row (last value). Please see the output below. Can somebody help to store all the values in "yy"

Thanks in advance. I am a beginner to R.

```
arrPol <- as.matrix(unique(TN_97_Lau_Cot[,6]))
arrYear <- as.matrix(unique(TN_97_Lau_Cot[,1]))

for (ij in length(arrPol)){
    for (ik in length(arrYear)) {
     newPolicy <- subset(TN_97_Lau_Cot, POLICY == as.character(arrPol[ij]) & as.numeric(arrYear[ik]))
     yy <- newPolicy[which.min(newPolicy$min_dist),]
  }
}
```

Output:

```
YEAR DIVISION STATE COUNTY CROP POLICY STATE_ABB LRPP min_dist
1: 2016        8    41     97   21 699609        TN    0      2.6
```

Here is a image of "TN_97_Lau_Cot" matrix.

[image]

Comment: You need to create `yy` ahead of time and identify where in `yy` each value should be stored, i.e. `yy[ij,ik]`.

Comment: Can you give us some sample data from the variables you are working with? There may be ways of vectorising or using `lapply` depending on what you're trying to do.

Comment: I agree but for each ij there are multiple rows/values as shown in the outoput from which "min" is estimated and should be stored.

Comment: @Oliver. Please see the image in my question.

Comment: We can't do anything with an image. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Oliver: Please download the data from this link (CSV file).  https://bft.usu.edu/jnfbk

Comment: @ Oliver. I need to find the minimum distance (min_dist) from col 9 for each year and unique policy number in col 6. Hope you understood my question.

Comment: So for each year, and each unique policy number, you want to know the minimum value of `min_dist`?

Comment: Or are you expecting the minimum value for `min_dist` for each year and the policy number it came from?

Comment: @Oliver: Yes, you are correct. I can manually estimate the rows in Excel and tell but is there a way to estimate it in R.

Comment: So you're expecting the minimum value for min_dist for each year and the policy number it came from?

Comment: @OLiver: That is correct. I need the corresponding values of other columns as well as shown in the "Output" in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No loops required. There *could* be an easier way to do it, but two set-based steps are better than two loops. These are the two ways I would try and do it:

**base**

```
# Perform an aggregate and merge it to your data.frame.
TN_97_Lau_Cot_Agg <- merge(
  x = TN_97_Lau_Cot, 
  y = aggregate(min_dist ~ YEAR + POLICY, data = TN_97_Lau_Cot, min),
  by = c("YEAR","POLICY"),
  all.x = TRUE
)

# Subset the values that you want.
TN_97_Lau_Cot_Final <- unique(subset(TN_97_Lau_Cot_Agg, min_dist.x == min_dist.y))
```

**data.table**

```
library(data.table)

# Convert your data.frame to a data.table.
TN_97_Lau_Cot <- data.table(TN_97_Lau_Cot)

# Perform a "window" function that calculates the min value for each year without reducing the rows.
TN_97_Lau_Cot[, minDistAggregate:=min(min_dist), by = c("YEAR","POLICY")]

# Find the policy numbers that match the minimum distance for that year.
TN_97_Lau_Cot_Final <- unique(TN_97_Lau_Cot[min_dist==minDistAggregate, -10, with=FALSE])
```

Comment: If you want to remove duplicate rows, use `unique()`

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. But, that's not the answer I was looking for. I want to know the "min_dist" for each policy number in each year. Hope it helps.

Comment: That wasn't what you said when I asked "So you're expecting the minimum value for min_dist for each year and the policy number it came from?" But I have edited my original answer. If that isn't the answer you're looking for then you are going to have to create an example output.

Comment: Thanks so much. This is the answer I was looking for. Many thanks.

Comment: No problem. Mark it as correct if you're happy with it.

Comment: Click the tick to the left of this answer.